# How to use regular expressions to deal with Chinese punctuation symbols in C++

Tags: c++, chinese-locale

I want to achieve such a result:

Before:

> 有人可能会问：“那情绪、欲望、冲动、强迫症有什么区别呢？”

After:

> 有人可能会问  那情绪 欲望 冲动 强迫症有什么区别呢

To space replace Chinese punctuation symbols.

I tried to use `replace` and `replace_if` function but failed. The code like this:

```
char myints[] = "有人可能会问：“那情绪、欲望、冲动、强迫症有什么区别呢？”";
std::vector<char> myvector ;            
std::replace_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), "\\pP", " ");                    
std::cout << "myvector contains:";
for (std::vector<char>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
std::cout << ' ' << *it;
std::cout << '\n';
```

Comment: Have you tried `std::regex_replace`?

Comment: You have a vector of **bytes** (C++ type `char`). `replace_if` operates on individual vector elements. Chinese characters are not bytes. They are represented by sequences of two or more bytes, hopefully encoded with UTF-8. `replace_if` cannot possibly work here even if you get the syntax right. It is recommended to work with actual **characters** rather than bytes. In C++, characters have type `wchar_t`. Good luck.

Comment: @n.m.: `wchar_t` doesn't go nearly as far as you'd hope.  If you want to work with actual characters, use a Unicode Library.

Comment: The contents and size of `myints` depends on the encoding of the system, the compiler, and potentially the active code page at the time of compilation on the machine used to compile.  In no combination does `replace_if` or `cout << *it` do what you want on an 8-bit/byte system.

Comment: Uh, I also just noticed, `replace_if` doesn't even remotely do what you think it does.  The third argument is supposed to be a _function_.  You probably wanted `std::regex`?

Comment: Well, you had a problem.  Then you thought "I should use regular expressions to solve this problem!".  You now have two problems.

Comment: @MooingDuck well if you are on Windows you may have to do it sooner than later, otherwise wchar_t is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: why this kind question get 2 upvotes?

Comment: because its very interesting and possibly useful to others

Comment: @Matt: Foolish use of `replace_if`, it's actually not a bad question.  It's also on a topic that (I suspect) is tricky to google for.

Comment: Other than the related link on the right: [How to read an UTF-8 encoded file containing Chinese characters and output them correctly on console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195262/how-to-read-an-utf-8-encoded-file-containing-chinese-characters-and-output-them?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you did mean to use a regular expression, rather than a character-by-character replacement function... Here's what I meant by using `std::regex_replace`. There's probably a more elegant regex that generalizes with fewer surprises, but at least this works for your example.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring s(L"有人可能会问：“那情绪、欲望、冲动、强迫症有什么区别呢？”");

    // Replace each run of punctuation with a space; use ECMAScript grammar
    s = std::regex_replace(s, std::wregex(L"[[:punct:]]+"), L" ");

    // Remove extra space at ends of line
    s = std::regex_replace(s, std::wregex(L"^ | $"), L"");

    return (s != L"有人可能会问 那情绪 欲望 冲动 强迫症有什么区别呢"); // returns 0
}
```

Comment: compiler says regex_replace is not member of std ‘wregex’ is not a member of ‘std’ my gcc's version is 4.6.3

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could upgrade to gcc 4.9 or use boost.