# Read special characters from file

Tags: c++, character-encoding, utf

For a few day I am trying to solve an ecoding issue in my C++ code.
I have the following content of a txt file (saved utf-8): "quÃ©bÃ©cois". (and I have only read rights over the file).
I am reading it with ReadFile function in a std::string variable.

1. The first surpize is that the strContnet is not "quÃ©bÃ©cois", but "ï»¿quÃƒÂ©bÃƒÂ©cois". (double encoded ??)
   Why?
2. How cand I read it's content in a std::string variable in order to obtaint "québécois" (utf8 to ansi?)

Until now I have two ways to get somewere close to what I want but none satisfie me enought.
1. Convert from:
 std::string to std::wstring (using MultiByteToWideChar)
 create a CString from the wstring
 use CT2CA to obtaint a new std::string
 and finally use agin MultiByteToWideChar for a final std::wstring containint "québécois"

I thing the method is unsafe and not verry smart and I have a wstring not string.

2. I found this article:
   [How to convert from UTF-8 to ANSI using standard c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562736/how-to-convert-from-utf-8-to-ansi-using-standard-c)
   And if I use utf8_to_string function twice I obtain what I want, but still I am not sure if it's the wright way.

Can anybody help me with a solution for this issue?

Comment: it appears double-encoded because you don't read it using utf-8

Comment: How can I read using utf8?

Comment: something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20195262/how-to-read-an-utf-8-encoded-file-containing-chinese-characters-and-output-them